# Which distro uses a Kernel 3.19 or above

Tags: linux-kernel, intel-graphics

I am looking for a distro that supports Intel HD 6000 , i believe kernel 3.19 and above is needed.

So does anyone know of a beginner friendly distro

Many thanks

Comment: It's possible to selectively upgrade the kernel of your preferred distribution, or install a suitable third party driver/module on it. Choosing your distribution on the basis of what kernel is ships is neither necessary nor advisable.

Answer (score 1):

This is one that skirts a line of "broadly Opinion Based" So i'll try to give you the facts, and let you sort out your thoughts...

NOTE: I couldn't say 100% sure that the `intel HD 6000` would work correctly, this list is based on kernel version requirements. For graphics card support, you'd really have to test one to find out.

First you can look at [Distro Watch's Major Distribution List](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major) for a lot of information on things that are available to you.

- Ubuntu `15.04` Is at Kernel Version `3.19`
- Fedora core `22` is at `4.0.4`
- Slackware `current` version is at `4.1.6`
- OpenSuse's `tumbleweed` is at version `4.2.1`
- Debians `unstable` branch is at `4.2`
- Arch is at version `4.2.3`

Of these, Most people would *probably* rank ubuntu is the "most beginner friendly" Followed by OpenSuse/Fedora... But that is HIGHLY arguable.

It also depends on whether or not you feel "beginner friendly" means "Anyone can use it" or "I will learn a lot from installing and using this"

Many would argue that for someone trying to learn linux in all its glory, `Arch` is the way to go. Others would say that is unnecessarily hard.

I recommend using those I've listed as a starting point for research and deciding what sounds good to you

Comment: I'd first ask around your friends/neighbor geek what tey are using, and go with that. You'll need them sooner or later...